# How to split an SQL Table into half and send the other half of the rows to new columns with SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Country    Percentage

India      12%
USA        20%
Australia  15%
Qatar      10%
```

Output :

```
Country1    Percentage1     Country2     Percentage2
India       12%             Australia    15%
USA         20%             Qatar        10%
```

For example there is a table Country which has percentages, I need to divide the table in Half and show the remaining half (i.e. the remaining rows) in the new columns. I've also provided the table structure in text.

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: How to do we know which column to use for each country?

Comment: jarlh -- Is the question not clear via image ?      The order in which the countries are present, in that order only we need to split. Like in the e.g. - India and USA are the 1st and 2nd countries and the following countries should follow in the other columns.

Comment: Some users here are not allowed to access web images (company policies), so they can't even see your images...

Comment: "The order in which the countries are present". Tables are inherently unsorted, so in what order are they present? The order you see means nothing unless you use `order by`. And what is supposed to happen if the number of countries is uneven?

Comment: If the table has odd number of records, how you want to split the table?. Also, it will be great if you could provide the text instead of images.

Comment: @HoneyBadger : I have not used the order by clause. This table is the result of Select * from Country.    Moreover, If the row count is in odd numbers, suppose - 5, then in the last two columns of the 3rd row should be empty.

Comment: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This is not a task for SQL. This is a task for whatever tool is presenting data to your users.

Answer (score 5):

First, this type of operation should be done at the application layer and not in the database.  That said, it can be an interesting exercise to see how to do this in the database.

I would use conditional aggregation or `pivot`.  Note that SQL tables are inherently unordered.  Your base table has no apparent ordering, so the values could come out in any order.

```
select max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then country end) as country_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 0 then percentage end) as percentage_1,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then country end) as country_2,
       max(case when seqnum % 2 = 1 then percentage end) as percentage_2       
from (select c.*,
             (row_number() over (order by (select null)) - 1) as seqnum
      from country c
     ) c
group by seqnum / 2;
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But the only problem with the this is the sequence is changing.. i.e. : 'USA' is coming in the third column -'country2' rather than it should come in 'country1', second row. Hope you got what am referring to. Otherwise the solution is rock solid. Please see if you can provide the solution for that. Thanks again.

Comment: @Nayan_07 . . . You need a way to specify the ordering.  That goes where `(select null)` goes.  I see no natural way to order your rows, although you could put in an explicit `order by` that checks each value.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    declare @t table
(
Country VARCHAR(20),
percentage INT
)
declare @cnt int

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES('India',12),('USA',20),('Australia',15),('Quatar',12)

select @cnt = count(1)+1 from @t

;with cte
as
(
    select
    SeqNo = row_number() over(order by Country),
    Country,
    percentage
    from  @t
)
select 
*
from cte c1
left join cte c2
on c1.seqno = (c2.SeqNo-@cnt/2)
and c2.SeqNo >= (@cnt/2)
where c1.SeqNo <= (@cnt/2)
```

Comment: @Jayasurya : First of all , am not getting the required output. The sequence of the output is not the desired one I mentioned. Secondly, there are lot of rows in the table am using. I've just given an example with 4 rows. Hence i cant insert values one by one in the temporary table @t that you've mentioned.

Comment: I used the temporary table just for the demo, you can directly use your table instead of @t. Also, If you need any other order for seq, then specify that in the order by for Row_number()

Answer (score 2):

My variant

```
SELECT 'A' Country,1 Percentage INTO #Country
UNION ALL SELECT 'B' Country,2 Percentage
UNION ALL SELECT 'C' Country,3 Percentage
UNION ALL SELECT 'D' Country,4 Percentage
UNION ALL SELECT 'E' Country,5 Percentage

;WITH numCTE AS(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Country) RowNum,
    COUNT(*)OVER() CountOfCountry
  FROM #Country
),
set1CTE AS(
  SELECT Country,Percentage,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Country) RowNum
  FROM numCTE
  WHERE RowNum<=CEILING(CountOfCountry/2.)
),
set2CTE AS(
  SELECT Country,Percentage,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY Country) RowNum
  FROM numCTE
  WHERE RowNum>CEILING(CountOfCountry/2.)
)
SELECT
  s1.Country,s1.Percentage,
  s2.Country,s2.Percentage
FROM set1CTE s1
LEFT JOIN set2CTE s2 ON s1.RowNum=s2.RowNum

DROP TABLE #Country
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to try something. I have used the function OFFSET. It does the requirement i think for your sample data, but dont know if its bulletproof all the way:

**SQL Code**

```
declare @myt table (country nvarchar(50),percentage int)
insert into @myt
values
('India'      ,12),
('USA'        ,20),
('Australia'  ,15),
('Qatar'      ,10),
('Denmark',10)



DECLARE @TotalRows int    
SET @TotalRows = (select CEILING(count(*) / 2.) from @myt);

WITH dataset1 AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by country ) as rn from (
SELECT Country,percentage from @myt a   
ORDER BY country OFFSET 0 rows FETCH FIRST @TotalRows ROWS ONLY
) z
)

,dataset2 AS (
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by country ) as rn from (
SELECT Country,percentage from @myt a    
ORDER BY country OFFSET @TotalRows rows FETCH NEXT @TotalRows ROWS ONLY
) z
)

SELECT * FROM dataset1 a LEFT JOIN dataset2 b ON a.rn = b.rn
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want descending alphabetic country names, but the left column is determined by where India is located in the result:

```
with CoutryCTE as (
      select c.*
           , row_number() over (order by country)-1 as rn
      from country c  
      )
, Col as (
     select rn % 2 as num from CoutryCTE
     where Country = 'India'
     )
select max(case when rn % 2 =  Col.num then country end) as country_1
     , max(case when rn % 2 =  Col.num then percentage end) as percentage_1
     , max(case when rn % 2 <> Col.num then country end) as country_2
     , max(case when rn % 2 <> Col.num then percentage end) as percentage_2       
from CoutryCTE
cross join Col
group by rn / 2
;
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f58a3f/1)

```
| country_1 | percentage_1 | country_2 | percentage_2 |
|-----------|--------------|-----------|--------------|
|     India |          12% | Australia |          15% |
|       USA |          20% |     Qatar |          10% |
```

nb: this is extremely similar to an earlier answer by Gordon Linoff